# How to create something like virtual field & hardcode a value in mongodb aggregation $project?

Tags: mongodb

Consider I want to show the following document:

```
   {
     "_id" : ObjectId("512bc95fe835e68f199c8686"),
     "AuthorName": "dave", 
     "VirtualField" : "hardcoded_Value"
   }
```

Actual Document stored in MongoDB

```
   {
     "_id" : ObjectId("512bc95fe835e68f199c8686"),
     "author": "dave",
     "score" : 80
   }
```

Can I do something like :

```
collection.aggregate([
    { $project: {
        _id: 1,
        "AuthorName": "$author",
        "VirtualField": "hardcoded_Value"
       }
    }
    ], function (err, doc) {
        if (err) return console.error(err);
        console.dir(doc);
    }
);
```

Could anyone tell how to do the same?

Note: I don't want to do the same after retrieving the document.

---

Got Error :

```
[MongoError: exception: field path references must be prefixed with a '$' ('hardcoded_Value ]
  name: 'MongoError',
  errmsg: 'exception: field path references must be prefixed with a \'$\' (\'hardcoded_Value\'',
  code: 15982,
  ok: 0 }
```

---

Getting the following error on using: `"VirtualField": {$concat: ["hardcoded_Value"]}`

```
{ [MongoError: exception: invalid operator '$concat']
  name: 'MongoError',
  errmsg: 'exception: invalid operator \'$concat\'',
  code: 15999,
  ok: 0 }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use `concat` here: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/aggregation/#exp._S_concat

Like so:

```
"VirtualField": {$concat: ["hardcoded_Value"]}
```

Comment: Please verify that something is missed out in your answer..? I am getting error. Updated in my question..

Comment: @AmolMKulkarni looks like concat is only available from 2.4 onwards. What is your version?

Comment: @AmolMKulkarni You need to upgrade

Answer (score 2):

There are quite a lot of creative ways to solve this.

Using `concat` from @Sammaye is one. But it is only available from MongoDB 2.4 onwards.

I did one using `$ifNull`

```
    "VirtualField": {$ifNull: [null,"hardcoded_Value"]}
```

That works.

However as you might have noticed this is a common feature and has been requested already in this JIRA.

https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-5991

Comment: very nice logic... designed for something else but used for something else very efficiently :-) 
Thanks..

Comment: It is good to note this is a little more work than concat, it adds effectively an if statement to each line, but this is a good trick