# Mongo circle query

Tags: mongodb

Can I run a query to get the exact number of documents?

I have collection:

```
    > db.circle.find()
    { "_id" : 1 }
    { "_id" : 2 }
    { "_id" : 3 }
```

Execute the query:

```
    > db.circle.find().skip(2).limit(2)
    { "_id" : 3 }
```

In response 1 document, but I need 2

What is the best way to see this response?

```
    { "_id" : 3 }
    { "_id" : 1 }
```

Comment: You know that `skip(2)` skips the first two documents so you would not see the document with id 2 in your result?  Are you asking how to skip the document whose id is 2 (if so, `$ne`).  Or are you asking how to programmatically skip the least amount so that the number of documents returned is exactly the limit?  (Although in the latter case there is no guarantee you would get 3 and 1.)  It is not clear what you are asking.

Comment: @RayToal He wants to take two items after the skip, and continue from the beginning if there are not enough left. Hence, the title: Circle query

Comment: Yes, i want to continue from the beginning if there are not enough left

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a way to solve this in one query using the aggregation framework:

```javascript
result = db.circle.aggregate([
    {   
        $project: {
            virtual_id: { $ifNull: [null, [1, 2]] }
            // extra fields go here...
        }
    },
    { $unwind: '$virtual_id' },
    { $sort: { virtual_id: 1, _id: 1 } },

    { $skip: 2 },
    { $limit: 2 }   
]);
```

This basically makes a copy of the data set, appends it to the end and then applies the skip & limit operations.

The steps:

1. The `$project` adds the `virtual_id` field, having as value the array `[1, 2]` to each document. The `$ifNull` way to add a field with a static value is a nice hack I managed to find in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16272996/390819).
2. `$unwind` by `virtual_id` doubles the data set.
3. `$sort` makes sure that the two concatenated data sets are ordered correctly. After this operation, the `_id` values will be: `1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3` .
4. `$skip` and `$limit` do the obvious

#### Note 1

If you need any other fields to be retrieved in addition to `_id`, you should specify them in the `$project` operation (`_id` is retrieved by default). For example, to get the values of `extra_field` and `yet_another_field` in the output, do:

```javascript
        $project: {
            virtual_id: { $ifNull: [null, [1, 2]] },
            extra_field: 1,
            yet_another_field: 1
        }
```

#### Note 2

This solution may not be suitable for very large data sets, because:

- the output of the aggregation framework is limited in size (16MB , I believe)
- the `$sort` operation is potentially expensive, as there cannot be any index defined to cover `virtual_id`

Answer (score 0):

```
The cursor.skip() method is often expensive because it requires the server to walk from 
the beginning of the collection or index to get the offset or skip position before 
beginning to return result
```

SO in your code, `db.circle.find().skip(2).limit(2)` ,it will skip first 2 documents and will return next 2.
For more details refer [cursor.skip()](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.skip/)

If you want to skip a document with a specific ID, then use [$ne](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/ne/) operator :

```
 db.circle.find({"_id":{ "$ne" : 2}})
```

It will return you following documents:

```
{ "_id" : 3 }
{ "_id" : 1 }
```

Comment: I think in the specific case illustrated by the OP that's true. But if there were, say, 6 elements in the collection, and he did skip(5) he would expect Ids 6 and 1 to be returned

Comment: @w0lf : in that case,skip(5) will skip first 5 documents, and will return Id 6 only.

Comment: I was describing what the OP wants; not what the actual results would be.

Answer (score 0):

I used `db.collection.count()`

> [Docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.count/):
>
> db.collection.count()
>
> Returns the count of documents that would match a find() query. The
>   db.collection.count() method does not perform the find() operation but
>   instead counts and returns the number of results that match a query.

Comment: I need to perform 2 requests, if I need more documents?